# What is the difference between entries and entry values in android listPreferences xml?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, listpreference

**Here is my code:**

How do they differ and which values get displayed on the dialog?

```
<ListPreference
    android:entryValues="@array/level"
    android:entries="@array/level"
    android:key="pref_numberOfChoices"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:summary="@string/level_description"
    android:title="@string/level_title"
    android:defaultValue="3"/>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can check out the official doc about [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html).

> **android:entries**       The human-readable array to present as a list.
>
> **android:entryValues**       The array to find the value to save for a
>   preference when an entry from entries is selected.

I other words: *entries* is what you see in the list and *entryValues* are the values you want to save when you do some action with the respective entry value.

Answer (score 7):

Basically it is **key-value pair combination** in which 
**android:entries - Act as Values**
and 
**android:entryValues - Act as Key**

For example :
Usually we show list of Countries(android:entries) India, US, Nepal etc in spinner
and when user select any of these country, programmer collect Id(android:entryValues ) associated with these countries to do operation.

For proper functioning **count of key and value must be exactly same** in list preference.
If android:entries are more and android:entryValues are less then if user select any entries OS wouldn't find any android:entryValues associated with that entry and app will crash :(